# protect existing sqlite database with sqlite-jdbc-crypt throws sqlite error or missing database (unsupported file format)

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, crypt

I have an already existing database that I want to protect using [sqlite-jdbc-crypt](https://github.com/Willena/sqlite-jdbc-crypt) driver. The code I am using is as under. I tried to accomplish the task in three different ways as marked by action = 1, 2 or 3 in following code. But every time it throws SQLITE_ERROR missing database (unsupported file format). if I comment line <1> then exception doesn't occur but the database file doesn't get protected.

```
    static void LockPlainDatabase()
    {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            int action = 3;
            //Using Chacha20
            SQLiteMCChacha20Config cfg;
            if (action == 1) {
                cfg = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault();
                conn = cfg.createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/plain2cryptdb.sqlite3");
                cfg.setPragma(Pragma.KEY, "myKey"); // <1>
                cfg.apply(conn);
                // above line throws SQLITE_ERROR missing database (unsupported file format)
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("PRAGMA key='myKey'");
            }
            else if (action == 2) {
                cfg = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault();
                conn = cfg.createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/plain2cryptdb.sqlite3");
                cfg.withKey("myKey");   // <1>
                cfg.apply(conn);
                // above line throws SQLITE_ERROR missing database (unsupported file format)
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("PRAGMA key='myKey'");
            }
            else if (action == 3) {
                cfg = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault();
                conn = cfg.createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/plain2cryptdb.sqlite3");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                cfg.setPragma(Pragma.KEY, "myKey");
                cfg.applyCipherParameters(conn, stmt);
                //
                //  This code segment doesn't throw any exception 
                //  But doesn't protect the database as well
                //
            }
            else if (action == 4) {
                conn = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault()
                        .createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/plain2cryptdb.sqlite3");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("PRAGMA key='Used2be1'");
                //
                //  This code segment doesn't throw any exception 
                //  But doesn't protect the database as well
                //
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try {
                if (stmt != null)
                    stmt.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally
            {
                try {
                    if (conn != null)
                        conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Further to note.

(1) I created a new database with protection successfully with following code.

```
            conn = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault().withKey("myKey")
                    .createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/cryptdb.sqlite3");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("PRAGMA key='myKey'");
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE ATBL (COL1 VARCHAR (100))");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ATBL (COL1) VALUES ('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DATA1')");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO ATBL (COL1) VALUES ('INSERT INTO DATA2 (DC1) VALUES (''SQLITE JDBC CRYPT DRIVER TEST'')')");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM ATBL");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("COL1"));
            }
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
```

then copied cryptdb.sqlite3 to crypt2plaindb.sqlite3. 
(2) Removed the protection successfully from crypt2plaindb.sqlite3 with following code.

```
            conn = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault().withKey("myKey")
                    .createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/crypt2plaindb.sqlite3");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("PRAGMA key='myKey'");
            stmt.execute("PRAGMA rekey=''");
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
```

then copied crypt2plaindb.sqlit3 to plain2cryptdb.sqlite3. 
 (3) Again tried to protect plain2cryptdb.sqlite3 with following code. It executes without exception but doesn't protect the database.

```
            conn = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault()
                        .createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/plain2cryptdb.sqlite3");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute("PRAGMA key='myKey'");
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break, I was able to protect existing database. The code is as under:

```
                conn = SQLiteMCChacha20Config.getDefault()
                        .createConnection("jdbc:sqlite:E:/sqlitedata/plain2cryptdb.sqlite3");
                stmt = conn.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("PRAGMA rekey='myKey'");
```